# UICollectionView begin flow from bottom right

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

as I am exploring the fairly new UICollectionView, I wondered how I could turn the flow of the items round so that they fill up from the bottom right instead of the top left corner.

Would be nice to get some feedback here.

Thanks again!